# meaning of this regular expression /(\+\d{2})/

Tags: regex, vb.net

Can anyone tell me meaning or possible values of below regular expression?

```
/(\+\d{2})/
```

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a good source to learn about regular expressions. I also found this site which explains any expression: http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%28%5C%2B%5Cd%7B2%7D%29.

Answer (score 2):

Plus followed by a number on 2 digits.

This matches for instance: `+23`

Answer (score 0):

A + followed by 2 digits: `+23 +01` etc.